# Возможно ли автоматически подключить declare(strict_types = 1) в нескольких файлах?

Tags: php, php7

Есть к примеру большой проект на каком-либо фреймворке: Yii2, Laravel или Symfony и т.д. Да или просто свой проект. Файлов не один десяток, может быть сотен.

Есть ли какой-либо способ ко всем контроллерам, моделям, вьюъхам, компонентам, модулям и т.д. подключить режим `declare(strict_types = 1)` автоматом? Своего рода *autoload*.

Ведь очень напряжно писать в каждом файле вручную (во всяком случае в уже существующих).

Да, можно написать какой-нибудь код по чтению файлов, вставке в файлы директивы, но есть большая доля вероятности, что где-нибудь вставится неправильно, с чем-нибудь сольется и выбьет ошибки и прочее.

В общем, вопрос: можно ли? Если да, то как?

Comment: а зачем абсолютно в каждом файле, у вас все приложение весь фреймворк строго типизирован?

Comment: @Naumov ну вот капризы у меня такие, хочу все контроллеры, модели, вьюхи, компоненты и модули переписать....и дальше в строгом работать режиме уже все делать ...вопрос не в этом....вопрос не частный, а общий. Что если кто-то так захочет сделать, включая меня

Comment: по документации, вроде как специально сделали эту опцию только для файла. По этому я думаю есть.только один способ прописать все в ручную, или написать скрипт который допишит заветную строку в каждый фаил. Ну и на последок можно покапаться в опциях php интерпритатора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет.

Первоначально можно сделать автозамену (скриптом или программой) `<?php\n` в начале файла на `<?php\ndeclare(strict_types=1);\n`

Потом можно в любимой IDE поменять шаблон для PHP-файлов, добавив туда эту строку. В PhpStorm - это в `Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > PHP*`

Comment: Да, только проблема в том, что не требуется писать это в каждом файле, а лишь для определенных категорий, которые где-либо будут указаны, например для контроллеров только. А-ля автолоадер классов, иначе бы и вопроса не стояло бы.........На данный момент мне лень, а потом, скорее всего, что-то подобное сам и напишу, мелкий плагин для таких вещей.